# apache2 403 forbidden on parent directory

Tags: apache2, config

When I try to access the parent directory, say localhost/parent, it gives me 403 forbidden. However if I access the sub-directory, say localhost/parent/index.html, it goes through.
I believe it's a config issue but could anyone walk me through a bit here?
I tried to change the apache2.conf as many people suggested but it doesn't work.(shown below)

```
<Directory "your directory here">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The following is what error log says:

```
[Mon Jul 03 11:32:51.028149 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 4899] [client 127.0.0.1:42462] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/hub/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Comment: What does the error log say?  It could be underlying permissions, not the Apache config.

Comment: What do you expect to see in /hub/? A directory listing? Some specific file?

Comment: No I am expecting it to load the index.html file in hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a config file issue,

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

Make index.php as the first option and it solved the problem